# Azure WebJob QueueTrigger Retry Policy

Tags: azure, azure-webjobssdk, azure-storage-queues, retrypolicy

I would like to have my queue retry failed webjobs every 90 minutes and only for 3 attempts.

When creating the queue i use the following code

```
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        IRetryPolicy linearRetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5400), 3);
        queueClient.DefaultRequestOptions.RetryPolicy = linearRetryPolicy;
        triggerformqueue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("triggerformqueue");
        triggerformqueue.CreateIfNotExists();
```

However when simulating a failed webjob attempt the queue uses the default retry policy.
I'm i missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be thinking about this backwards. Queues don't actually perform behavior. Instead what I am guessing you want to do is have a web job that is configured to pull messages from a queue and then if it fails to process the message from a queue for some reason have the web job retry 90 minutes later. In this case you just need to set the invisibility timeout to be 90 minutes (default is 30 seconds) which will ensure that if the message isn't fully processed (ie - GetMessage and DeleteMessage are both called) then the message will reappear on the queue 90 minutes later.

Take a look at this [Getting Started with Queue Storage](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/) document for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason why for the delay between failed webjobs is in Africa we usually experience electricity blackouts. These usually last for  plus minus 2 hours, during this time our public facing servers are off. So in order to improve probability of delivery we have opted for azure storage queues. I followed the [Azure example](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-get-started/) in this example they demonstrated the webjob sdk and i have not seen a handle to the message  in webjob which will allow me to set invisibility.

Comment: see [similar question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937782/queuetrigger-attribute-visibility-timeout) with no answer

Answer (score 0):

There is something like Azure WebJobs SDK Extensions and ErrorTriggerAttribute (it isn't yet available in nuget 1.0.0-beta1 package, but you have access to public repository)

> public static void ErrorMonitor(
>       [ErrorTrigger("0:30:00", 10, Throttle = "1:00:00")] TraceFilter filter, 
>       TextWriter log)

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions#errortrigger

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your RetryPolicy when you add an item to the queue, not on the queue itself, eg.

```
var queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("myQueue");
queue.CreateIfNotExists();

options = new QueueRequestOptions { RetryPolicy = linearRetryPolicy };
await queue.AddMessageAsync(yourMessage, null, new TimeSpan(0, delayMinutes, 0), options, null);
```