# How to stop an Azure WebJobs queue message from being deleted from an Azure Queue?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I'm using Azure WebJobs to poll a queue and then process the message.

Part of the message processing includes a hit to 3rd party HTTP endpoint. (e.g. a Weather api or some Stock market api).

Now, if the hit to the api fails (network error, 500 error, whatever) I try/catch this in my code, log whatever and then ... what??

If I continue .. then I *assume* the message will be deleted by the WebJobs SDK.

How can I:

1) Say to the SDK - please don't delete this message (so it will be retried automatically at the next queue poll *and* when the message is visible again).
2) Set the invisibility time value, when the SDK pops a message off the queue for processing.

Thanks!

Comment: Based on the content posted here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to/#poison, I believe the message is not deleted if your function throws an error. Can you try by logging the exception and then rethrowing that exception?

Comment: Assuming you dont continue/handle error but allow it to fail - and if your request fails more than 5 times -the message is pushed into another queue what is called a `posion-{{your_queue_name}}` - you can write a listener listening to this queue to process the failed message. Please clarify what you mean by invisibility value? You mean a lock.

Comment: @JS_GodBlessAll Reading the documentation, `5` is the default value for the number of retries but is configurable. If we set this value to a really high number, then the message won't move to poison queue (see `Manual poison message handling` section). Am I correct?

Comment: @GauravMantri : Am not sure about configuring retries cause when I used SDK version (3 months back) it did not let me. However I could configure and did configure 1) Polling interval 2) and the no of messages allowed to be dequeued - this is what I did. May be the newer version let you configure the failures too

Comment: Also @GauravMantri and @ Pure.Krome - I believe (vaguely remember) adding another dll to achieve the same - that might be for CRON jobs - not sure though, also these values are capped at a max value - somewhere hidden in the docs .

Comment: What kind of queue?  Azure queues are leased based and should not auto delete unless explicitly called

Comment: @CtrlDot - the WebJobs SDK is a little magical wrapper for various scenarios .. one being Queue's. This means it's does all the boring plumbing of things like 'pop message(s) from queue', 'delete message when the method finished', etc. So the 'what kind of queue' is sorta irrelevant here. It's just an azure queue with the WebJobs doing all the boring heavy lifting, leaving the exciting 'what do we do with this message from the queue', up to you.

Comment: @GauravMantri I'm trying to avoid re-throwing the exception because that's the whole point. I don't want to have exceptions in my logs and rethrow only for the framework to handle it. I'm already 'handing' it .. so i thought I can just flip a switch (at that point) so the wrapper SDK will know what I'm manually trying to do.

Comment: I have not used WebJobs as such but your question intrigued me so I read a bit about it (so I may be wrong) and based on my little knowledge, here's some of things I could think you can do - 1) change the default dequeue count from 5 to a higher number so that it is not deleted by the framework automatically after 5 retries or 2) if the message fails, create a copy of the message and repost in the queue and let framework delete your original message?

Comment: 1) This still means I need to re-throw. :/ 2) Nope, because then the deque count, etc all resets back when the message is re-added.

Answer (score 8):

> *Now, if the hit to the api fails (network error, 500 error, whatever) I try/catch this in my code, log whatever and then ... what??*

The Webjobs SDK behaves like this: If your method throws an uncaught exception, the message is returned to the Queue with its `dequeueCount` property +1. Else, if all is well, the message is considered **successfully processed** and is deleted from the Queue - i.e. `queue.DeleteMessage(retrievedMessage);`

So don't gracefully catch the HTTP 500, throw an exception so the SDK gets the hint.

> *If I continue .. then I assume the message will be deleted by the WebJobs SDK.*

From https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-get-started.md#contosoadswebjob---functionscs---generatethumbnail-method:

> If the method fails before completing, the queue message is not deleted; after a 10-minute lease expires, the message is released to be picked up again and processed. This sequence won't be repeated indefinitely if a message always causes an exception. After 5 unsuccessful attempts to process a message, the message is moved to a queue named `{queuename}-poison`. The maximum number of attempts is configurable.

If you really dislike the hardcoded 10-minute **visibility timeout** (the time the message stays *hidden* from consumers), you can change it. See this answer by @mathewc:

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/34093943/4148708:

> In the latest v1.1.0 release, you can now control the visibility timeout by registering your own custom `QueueProcessor` instances via `JobHostConfiguration.Queues.QueueProcessorFactory`. This allows you to control advanced message processing behavior globally or per queue/function.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/MiscOperations/CustomQueueProcessorFactory.cs#L63

```cs
protected override async Task ReleaseMessageAsync(CloudQueueMessage message, FunctionResult result, TimeSpan visibilityTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
      // demonstrates how visibility timeout for failed messages can be customized
      // the logic here could implement exponential backoff, etc.
      visibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(message.DequeueCount);

      await base.ReleaseMessageAsync(message, result, visibilityTimeout, cancellationToken);
}
```